# output html not working for adding value

Tags: html, output

i am trying to display the output result in the html, but it is not displaying anything.

This is my code --

```
       <td><input type="text" id ="set1" name ="set1"></td>
       <td><input type="text" id ="set2" name ="set2"></td>
       <td><output style="display: inline" name="x" for="set1+set2"></output></td>
```

So how can i display the adding value of two input integer !!

Comment: you have two `set1` named elements

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan oops, it was a mistake, although it is not working

Comment: https://jsbin.com/nukazu/1/edit?html,css,js,output I don't think `+` inside  `for` is what you need. use JS instead.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `x`, also, you need to change the name of the inputs:

```html
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(set1.value)+parseInt(set2.value)">
    <td><input type="text" id="set1" name ="set1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="set2" name ="set2"></td>
    <td><output style="display: inline" name="x" for="set1 set2"></output></td>
 </form>
```

You could use Angular.js, which makes this a lot simpler:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <td><input type="number" ng-model="left"></td>
  <td><input type="number" ng-model="right"></td>
  <p>Answer: {{left + right}}</p>
</div>
```